# Получить разность 2 ух множеств в Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, orm

Есть сущность Projects.
Каждый элемент этой сущности имеет тип Project.

Из соседней базы я формирую `List<Project>` через DataReader(Так как на той базе нету Entity Framework)  и хочу произвести сравнение со своей сущностью.

Мне нужно получить элементы, которые есть в моей сущности, но отсутствуют в соседней базе.

Я пытался сделать такую штуку:

```
var delProjects = db.Projects.Except(listProjects).ToList();
```

Но вылетает ошибка:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
>   occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to create a constant value of type
>   'WCFConsoleServer.Models.Project'. Only primitive types or enumeration
>   types are supported in this context.

Собственно вопрос, как избежать этой ошибки?

Я думаю, что проблема должна решиться, если всю сущность загрузить в память в List и только потом сделать вычитание множества. Но не сильно ли просядет производительность?

Можно явно пульнуть все это в foreach и сравнить, но мне кажется это тоже медлительно.

Есть еще какие-нибудь решения?

**upd**

Вот такая конструкция выдает аналогичную ошибку

```
db.Projects.Where(z=>!listProjects.All(y=>y.id!=x.id)).ToList();
```

Хотя она должна трактоваться, на мой взгляд, как

```
foreach
 foreach
  if
```

Comment: *"Можно явно пульнуть все это в foreach и сравнить, но мне кажется это тоже медлительно."* - Вы считаете, что *Except* как то по другому работает? Реализуйте для начала *IEqualityComparer*. По сути вам уже ответили

Comment: Мне казалось, что в этом случае List посылается на SQL-server в виде переменной таблицы и выполняется вычитание.

Comment: попробуйте поглядеть в отладчике что уходит на сервер, будите несказанно удивлены

Comment: Entity конечно же удобен, но механизм формирования и обработки запросов делает этот инструмент лишь пособием по изучению Linq.

Comment: А разве то, что я написал в UPD не должно работать без реализаций интерфейсов?

Comment: Хотите писать некрасивый код, пожалуйста, дело ваше. Реализовав интерфейс в одном месте, вы потом можете использовать его в любом  другом где вам надо сравнить две сущности *Project*. И да, поправьте, *Projects* - это не сущность, а коллекция

Answer (score 2):

Except - находит разность множеств, представленных двумя последовательностями, используя для сравнения значений компаратор проверки на равенство по умолчанию.
Если требуется сравнить две последовательности объектов определенного пользовательского типа данных, необходимо реализовать интерфейс IEqualityComparer универсальный во вспомогательном классе.В следующем примере кода показано, как реализовать этот интерфейс в пользовательском типе данных и предоставлять методы GetHashCode и Equals.
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Обновил вопрос. В этом подходе я сравниваю примитивные типы, а получ аналогичную ошибку

Comment: Попробуй так  var exceptProject = from dbproject in db.Projects
                    from projectlist in listProjects
                    where dbproject.id != projectlist.id
                    select projectlist;

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что вы насоздавали сущностей из стороннего источника и пытаетесь передать их в запрос. EF так не умеет. EF умеет передавать в запрос только примитивные типы или последовательности примитивных типов.

Вам надо предварительно собрать список их ключей в отдельную переменную:

```
var listProjectIds = listProjects.Select(y => y.id);

db.Projects.Where(x => !listProjectIds.Contains(x.id)).ToList(); // вот так работает
```

---

Вариант второй - не передавать список исключенных ключей на сервер в запросе, а выдернуть все и отфильтровать на клиенте:

```
db.Projects.AsEnumerable().Where(x => !listProjects.Any(y => y.id == x.id)).ToList(); // и вот так тоже работает
```